# use getPanoramaByLocation in python by pyv8

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, pyv8

I need to determine if a given location has street view or not.   So getPanoramaByLocation js API is the only way I can use as far as i know.

However, I have a python script to handle all those location data.  So I am wondering how can I call getPanoramaByLocation from python by using PyV8? Do I need to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js in python?

I am kinda new to this. So any hint and guide would be greatly appreciated!.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having had a quick look at the JS file you linked, the following answer applies for the most part [1] . You'd have to bridge both 'window' and 'document' somehow since these objects are not available in PyV8. The difficulty doing this is rather high, so if you're not very experienced in JS and python I'd look for other solutions. I recommend using a python native library instead. A quick [google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=python%20google%20maps) reveals quite a few options.

[1] [Loading JavaScript library in Python using PyV8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098477/loading-javascript-library-in-python-using-pyv8/23100907#23100907)