# Any quick way to get country name given a latitude and longitude

Tags: python

I wish to get the country name given a latitude and longitude But, wish to avoid API call.

I tried reverse_geocoder, which seems to be slow and erroneous for few cases. Example below:

```
import reverse_geocoder as rg
coordinates = (34.024375,-119)
rg.search(coordinates)
```

Any way to get country name given lat, lng?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to avoid an API call?

Comment: if you don't want to use internet downlaod countries shapefiles & map them accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643929/lookup-country-for-gps-coordinates-without-internet-access

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library `GeoPy` [Documentation link](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#specifying-parameters-once) but it requires online interaction:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="foo_bar")
coordinates = (34.024375, -119)
location = geolocator.reverse(coordinates)
country = location.address.split(',')[-1]

print(country)
```

Output of this code prints the country name for the given coordinates (lat/long), in this case `United States`

**Version 2:**

This code uses `reverse_geocoder` as you did:

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
import reverse_geocoder as rg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    coordinates = (34.024375, -119)
    location = rg.search(coordinates)
    country = location[0]['cc']

    print(country)
```

This prints the two-letter-code of the country, here `US`.
You need the `freeze_support()` because otherwise Python wants to start a new process without the current one finished.

Comment: You should note in your answer that this requires online interaction, since OP has specifically requested an approach that avoids it

Comment: @PranavHosangadi added a new solution without internet connection.