# How to get country name in android?

Tags: android, gps, location

Hi I am working with android.I had created a GPS app for getting the current location.Now How can I get the country name from the latitude and longitude value ? is it possible ? please help me and thanks :)

here is my code I used

```
 public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;
String countryCode,countryName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                Log.i("location", " "+latitude+" "+longitude);
                // \n is for new line
                try
                {Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name "+addresses.get(0).getLocality(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                }

                     catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude+countryName +"  "+countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
    });
}

 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Country name for GPS coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633504/country-name-for-gps-coordinates)

Comment: maybe it can help you : [Get country from coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082681/get-country-from-coordinates)

Comment: I used the above links it shows null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, without lat and long value, i got country name.

```
    String country = getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry();
```

.

Comment: But this gives 'United state' as country for all, this won't give the location where the user is

Comment: This isn't based on current location but the current Locale. I could have en_GB locale in China. This would return GB.

Answer (score 10):

```
    String country_name = null;
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
    for(String provider: lm.getAllProviders()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType") Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location!=null) {
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                    country_name = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), country_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
    Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(AppContext);
            try
            {
                myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(myList != null)
            {
                try
                {


                    String country = myList.get(0).getCountryName();}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) object, you can call the [getFromLocation(double, double, int) method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29). It will return a list of [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) objects that have a method [getLocality()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getLocality%28%29).

```
 import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(1.2, 2.2256, 1);
         if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: it returns null value

Comment: try with my new ans once

Comment: have u take a permission for internet bcoz its want internet

Comment: ya i already made and trying to toast adrees, but it shows null

Comment: dude its run veru beautiful at my side like this can u implement same as

Comment: and also see that u added import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder; these two lib while u import

Comment: try to add this same code in oncreate() not in button click and paste same code as i given to u just change only lat long which also original or genuine and also print not toast just try once

Comment: and listen i think your internet connectivity is very slow so i think after above soln just also try with Asyn task also

Comment: i just want to know that IS there any mistake with button click or else just for confirmation

Answer (score 1):

You can Get Country name from below mentioned json. Just pass your lat-long in address. And look for "long_name" which have "country,political" in "types" array.

i.e. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=23.022505,72.5713621&sensor=false

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Address> addresses=null;
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.latitude, loc.longitude, 1);
    System.out.println("add in string "+addresses.toArray().toString());
    String countryName = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    String countryCode = addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```