# Use OpenStreetMap to get the country name for a given set of GPS coordinates

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding

Does anybody know if there is a way to use OpenStreetMap (offline or API) to get the country name for a given set of GPS coordinates?

I'm not interested in using the Google or Geonames API  mentioned here: [Country name for GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633504/country-name-for-gps-coordinates)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) or one of the other [OSM-based search engines (geocoders)](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines).

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I've searched. THank you!

Comment: Example: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=32.7762719&lon=-96.7968559

Comment: @JonathanB. Thanks, perfect!