# Find Timezone using GPS coordinate (Latitude and Longitude) in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net

I have to find out local time zone from GPS coordinate (Lat and Long) in C#.net.
However I have searched around it and got solution by using Google map api.
I don't want to use Google api to find time zone using GPS coordinate.

Is there any other way to find time zone using GPS coordinate in C#.net?

Please suggest me any solution for it.

Comment: You would have to find a List of geo-fences that correspond to the timezones since time zones are not exactly based on geometry.

Comment: There's in built solution in .net.  There are many solutions apis libraries available to do this.  You could start here https://github.com/mj1856/GeoTimeZone/issues/15

Answer (score 1):

A coordinate is unambiguously in a single country, but a single country can have multiple timezones so even a country-level precision will not help you. How exactly do you imagine mapping the coordinates to a country and/or timezone without an external service, Google or not? I don't suppose you want to build your own Google Maps just to avoid using Google Maps (or Bing maps or whatever?

In any case, check if [this question with its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824949/use-openstreetmap-to-get-the-country-name-for-a-given-set-of-gps-coordinates) helps you to avoid using Google.

Comment: Ah, true, overlooked that fact in favour of worrying about countries on the same north-south axis having different time zones :) Will improve my answer, thanks.