# react-native get country code from GPS coordinates

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, geolocation

Is it possible to get country code by GPS location coordinates?

Currently, in my app I have implemented country rectangles but it is not accurate enough as every country has its own "shape" and rectangles are overflowing each other

I was wondering if you don't know about any react-native API where I'm able to post GPS coordinates and it will return info including country code.

I also need to be able to get the country code in offline mode.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the third party library for this. https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder. But it will not work in offline mode.

Comment: @JebinBenny so if I need to make it work even in offline mode there is no better option for me than shape-based algorithm?

Comment: Then you have to follow your idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3633619/4022607

Comment: @AhmadAyyaz is this a duplicate even when I'm asking for react-native solution? :)

Comment: you were asking about some API and it is mentioning Yahoo API. Also here is one more https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828498/4022607 with Google's geocoding services. I think you can use js with react native

Comment: @AhmadAyyaz I need to make offline-first so I will not be able to fire request when there is no internet connection but thanks anyway! :)